# Resize ndarrays

Tags: javascript, performance, typed-arrays

If I have a 2d [ndarray](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/ndarray) with side lengths of `x1`, `y1` and some data in it, how do I resize it to sidelengths `x2`,`y2` (where `x2 >= x1 && y2 >= y1`) so that the original data stays on the same indices and the operation doesn't always require allocating a new `TypedArray` and copying the data over and over.

Comment: I don't think that's possible due to the layout of the array. Do you really resize that often?

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that I have no idea up front how large it's going to get. I might be just around 10x10 but can get up to 1000x1000 or larger even. There isn't really a common usecase to optimize for it. Also, it's usually just one of the dimensions get changed, and only by a value of 2. So from a minimum of 3x3 going up to for example 40x40 which would be very frequent even if not typical, it would mean that I created 38 typedarrays for waste and copied the data over same amount of time. As you probably know, creating typedarrays is very slow in itself.

Comment: "*it's usually just one of the dimensions get changed, and only by a value of 2.*" sounds like a very specific usecase actually :-) I think you can only employ the techniques for growing/shrinking dynamic arrays.